# 'Kubernetes Jobs' in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-swarm, kubernetes-jobs

Docker Swarm is comparatively easier to maintain compared to Kubernetes so I was thinking of migrating from a Kubernetes cluster to a Docker Swarm cluster.

In my Kubernetes cluster, I used [Jobs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/jobs-run-to-completion/) extensively to spin up workers ad-hoc and is very critical to the main functions of the whole infrastructure. Best thing about Kubernetes Jobs is that they will shut down after a certain time limit after Job completion and recycle the resources.

I want to ask if there's a Kubernetes Jobs **equivalent** in Docker Swarm? So far I couldn't find official documentation on Docker website supporting this feature.

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: I also look for a solution to schedule a job on docker. but could not find any solution. Actually, Running a job is actually creating a container that does not run forever so docker SDK can be used ( https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/ ) in language you need to create a container.